# ion-col: attribute col-* is not applied with null value instead of false

Tags: html, typescript, ionic3, angular5

> **I want to set column width dynamically using col-* attribute.**
>
> [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-col-dynamic)

When I set `[attr.col-3]="false"` the width (col-3) is applied anyway.

To not apply col-3, I have to set the attribute to `null` on this way: `[attr.col-3]="false ? true : null"`.

**Is there any way to avoid adding the extra code when my conditional variable is a boolean?**

---

*Attribute col-3 is applied*

```
<ion-col [attr.col-2]="true" [attr.col-3]="false">col-2</ion-col>
```

*Attribute col-3 is not applied*

```
<ion-col [attr.col-2]="true" [attr.col-3]="false ? false : null">col-2</ion-col>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no other way to remove a attribute conditionally other then making it null. So you will have to write those extra lines of code. This will be needed:

```
<ion-col [attr.col-2]="true" [attr.col-3]="false ? false : null">col-2</ion-col>
```